# Handling time & slots in cardano-node clients

Tags: cardano-node, ledger

At hydra we do have a protocol which ensures something is not happening before some given deadline. The system would need to submit a transaction to set the deadline (`txA`) and another transaction once this deadline passed `txB`. The deadline is determined from a `txA`s upper validity bound given as slot `sA` . Let's assume that deadline is at slot `sT` and our scripts will ensure that `txB`s lower validity bound `sB` is `sB > sT`.

How would should our application determine the "right time" to publish transaction `txA` and `txB`?

We would need to know about current time (in slots) to kick things off by determining `sA` and `sT`. But also to know when `sB` is to not have a failing `txB`. So far we have tried two approaches:

1. Use `getLocalChainTip` from `cardano-api` to get the slot of the current chain tip. This seems to be the slot of the last seen block and hence up to `~20` seconds in the past. Which is fine for `txA`, but problematic for `txB` as we would need to know that offset for correctly determining sB .
2. Use `wallclockToSlot` from `ouroboros-consensus` to get the current slot given wall clock. This gives us the projected, actual slot (even hard-fork and era history compatible?) so it's better in determining slots `sA` and `sB`. However, we get a ledger error when submitting `txB` as the ledger seems to think it's still slot of the last block (like option 1). For example: `ApplyTxError [UtxowFailure (UtxoFailure (FromAlonzoUtxoFail (OutsideValidityIntervalUTxO (ValidityInterval {invalidBefore = SJust (SlotNo 220), invalidHereafter = SNothing}) (SlotNo 211))))]` when wall clock time and the `cardano-node` logs confirm was around slot `220` and the last block was forged at slot `211`.

Any other options or ideas how to handle this in a properly integrated, non-hacky fashion?

Comment: What is the scale of difference in time between `sA` and `sT`?

Comment: Does this difference have bounds? Preferably, a lower one?

Comment: For this issue at hand here we can assume `sT - sA` to be sufficiently low, say `20` to `50` slots. (We have other problems of the period being too high and not being able to compute the POSIXTime equivalent as it's "past the horizon")